# Generic's name as key in json in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a response from an API

```
const tradingApiResponse = {
  Timestamp: "2024-01-15T12:00:00",
  Ack: "Success",
  Version: 1,
  Build: "1.0.0",
  UserDeliveryPreferenceArray: {
    NotificationEnable: [
      { EventType: "ItemSold", EventEnable: "true" },
      { EventType: "ItemShipped", EventEnable: "false" }
    ],
  },
};
```

The `Timestamp`, `Ack`, `Version`, `Build` will be present in any request. and the next key `UserDeliveryPreferenceArray` in our case will vary depending on the request. I want to model this in interfaces/types. I know that this works

```
export interface EbayTradingRoot {
  Timestamp: string;
  Ack: string;
  Version: number;
  Build: string;
}

export interface UserDeliveryPreferenceArray {
  NotificationEnable: NotificationEnable[];
}

export interface NotificationEnable {
  EventType: string;
  EventEnable: string;
}
```

And then

```
export interface UserDeliveryPreferenceArrayResponse extends EbayTradingRoot {
  UserDeliveryPreferenceArray: UserDeliveryPreferenceArray;
}
```

But it should be a better way, something like

```
export interface EbayTradingRoot<T> {
  Timestamp: string;
  Ack: string;
  Version: number;
  Build: string;
  [T]: T;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the generic approach you demonstrated. You can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) if you use [`type`s instead of interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/types-vs-interfaces). That way you can compute new types based on the generic `EbayTradingRoot` type.

```
type UserDeliveryPreferenceArray = {
  NotificationEnable: NotificationEnable[];
};

type NotificationEnable = {
  EventType: string;
  EventEnable: string;
};

type EbayTradingRoot<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  Timestamp: string;
  Ack: string;
  Version: number;
  Build: string;
} & T;

type ExtendedEbayTradingRoot = EbayTradingRoot<{
  UserDeliveryPreferenceArray: UserDeliveryPreferenceArray;
}>;
// type ExtendedEbayTradingRoot = {
//     Timestamp: string;
//     Ack: string;
//     Version: number;
//     Build: string;
// } & {
//     UserDeliveryPreferenceArray: UserDeliveryPreferenceArray;
// }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgEQgGwJYDckgAqIQBmSEAdgMYQCCiiAhiFALxQDeAUFFAHID2wDEQwV6gvmQCiZegCM0EAFy8BQkWIwTpchQG0AugG4OAX2MdQkFYOGjxUmfOitO3STjLAAKuCVQ4wIgYZADmxm4ewNpOygFBocZmHBa%20UJKyjF4MACbBIQBKfAIAPF5QEAAewOTZcFD5EBR8iNnFcXkANFAArmQA1mR8AO5kAHyjLOxcUF4YALYQAfRzYLGBeeFQ1BR9a-Fh0wBqSHCaZMpk3XOySJsAQt0YaNl7G6ZQAGQz5pbQklU1CDZdKZHJ5QoCSYgkBZei5UIQ4DFVywBAodDYXAEYikSg0OiMZTwJCoTA4RD4QgkQh42gMECJUbGAD0zKgvzSALI2SB0Nh8IKRWAk04rO44tmCyWK1eCQ4YvFWx2soOCvFx0QpwkFyuN0QLLZioeTxe-nWcrFJk%20UzV3GJ6LJWKpuKodMJqJJGPJlJxNNdBIZ8rZJg4QA)

Answer (score 0):

Since `UserDeliveryPreferenceArray` is just the name of the interface, you can't infer that to use as key.

For type, you can do this:

```
export type UserDeliveryPreferenceArrayResponse = EbayTradingRoot & { UserDeliveryPreferenceArray: UserDeliveryPreferenceArray }
```

For interface:

```
interface UserDeliveryResponse {
  UserDeliveryPreferenceArray: UserDeliveryPreferenceArray
}

export interface IUserDeliveryPreferenceArrayResponse extends EbayTradingRoot, UserDeliveryResponse {}
```